# Every time i click a button it exits? (action listener)

Tags: java, swing

here is my code

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.Applet;

class Panell implements ActionListener {
    JButton button;
    JButton buttonTwo;
    JButton buttonThree;
    JButton buttonFour;
    JButton buttonFive;
    JTextArea textArea;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Panell gui = new Panell ();
        gui.go();
    }

    void go() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        button = new JButton("Monday");
        buttonTwo = new JButton("Tuesday");
        buttonThree = new JButton("Wednesday");
        buttonFour = new JButton("Thursday");
        buttonFive = new JButton("Friday");
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        button.addActionListener(this);
        buttonTwo.addActionListener(this);
        buttonThree.addActionListener(this);
        buttonFour.addActionListener(this);
        buttonFive.addActionListener(this);

        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(buttonTwo);
        panel.add(buttonThree);
        panel.add(buttonFour);
        panel.add(buttonFive);

        frame.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, textArea);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.WEST, panel);
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    } 

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if(event.getSource() == button) {
            textArea.setText("I've been clicked!");
        } else {
            System.exit(1);
        }
        {
            if(event.getSource() == buttonTwo) {
                textArea.setText("herro");
            } else {
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It keeps on exiting when i press a button? any ideas?

and also how can i add more action listeners?

Comment: this is `java`, right? not `C#`

Comment: Note that `System.exit(0)` is the correct way to end a program to indicate there is no error condition.  Why call  `System.exit(1)` here?

Answer (score 2):

You should exit (should you?) only if all of the conditions (buttons pressed) failed. Not one of them. 
You can use something like:

```
if(event.getSource() == button) {
    textArea.setText("I've been clicked!");
} else if(event.getSource() == buttonTwo) {
    textArea.setText("herro");
} else if(...
...//any other check
} else {
    System.exit(1); //button not found :(
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your application closes due to your "System.exit(1)".

The comparison "==" is ok in this case, since you compare object-references. But you have always to be sure if you compare references or objects. So it is more safe for you to change your code:

```
event.getSource() == button
```

to this

```
event.getSource().equals(button)
```

In addition you should check your if's: if the event source is not "button" (Monday), your "else" quits your application. The next comparison (to buttonTwo) will never be reached.

If the first comparison fits, the next comparison will fail and again the next "else" (of the second comparison) quits your application.

Change your code to something like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    if (event.getSource().equals(button)) {
        textArea.setText("I've been clicked!");
    } else if (event.getSource().equals(buttonTwo)) {
        textArea.setText("herro");
    } else {
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Get rid if the incorrect recommendation regarding == being incorrect here. It isn't.

Comment: You're right "==" is ok for object references. But anyway it is dangerouse for him to use this, since he defitivly does not differ between objects and references to objects. IMHO it's safer for him to use the .equals-syntax.

Comment: why is it safer to use equals in this situation? JButton does not override the equals method. And how does the recommendation solve his problem?

Comment: The situation is anyway - the knowledge of the developer is the problem in this case; he is not able to differ if he is dealing with objects or references. So why not recommend him to use (an also correct .equals) a style where he never can be wrong? But you are right: I changed my answer so he can decide for himself.